# JS Matrix Multiplication Issue

Tags: javascript, math, matrix

I'm having trouble with matrix multiplication code in JavaScript. If I run the function below with the following two matrices:

```
var m1 = [ [ 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 1, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1 ],
  [ 1, 0, 1 ],
  [ 0, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1 ] ];

var m2 = [ [ '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1' ] ];

var matrixMult = function (m1, m2) {
    console.log(m1);
    console.log(m2);
    console.log("m1 length: %d, m2[0].length: %d", m1.length, m2[0].length);
    if (m1.length != m2[0].length) {
            console.error("Incompatible matrix dimensions for multiplication.");
            return false;
    }

    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < m1[0].length; i++) {
            result[i] = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < m2.length; j++) {
                    var sum = 0;
                    for (var k = 0; k < m1.length; k++) {
                            sum += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
                    }
                    result[i][j] = sum;
            }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I get this error:

```
/path/to/file.js:58
                sum += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at matrixMult (...)
```

What's going wrong? Could the issue be that `m2.length` is only 1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is only a `m2[0]`, but your inner `for` loop runs from `0` to `m1.length`, which is bigger than `0`. So when it tries accessing `m2[1]` it throws the error.

Also by following definition of matrix multiplication

> Multiplication of two matrices is defined only if the number of columns of the left matrix is the same as the number of rows of the right matrix.

(Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29#Matrix_multiplication.2C_linear_equations_and_linear_transformations))

you cannot multiply your sample matrixes, because `m1` has 3 columns, but `m2` has only one row.

**EDIT**

Now that I understood your question correctly, I wrote a little function that might help you out:

```
function multiplyMatrix(m1, m2) {
    var result = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < m2.length; j++) {
        result[j] = [];
        for(var k = 0; k < m1[0].length; k++) {
            var sum = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
                sum += m1[i][k] * m2[j][i];
            }
            result[j].push(sum);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

multiplyMatrix(m1, m2);

// => [ [2, 4, 2] ]
```

Comment: Like I said, fix your matrixes first. You cannot multiple those two.

Comment: m1 has 7 columns (each inner array represents a column) and m2 has 7 rows but 1 column, so it's a (3,7) * (7,1)